# Reading directory in delphi 7 gives nothing

Tags: file, delphi, directory

I'm a delphi noob, and I simply try to read the the files in a directory (I will be doing sth with this files later).

I tried ouple methods, and nothing works - there is simply nothing outputed.

```
   directoryPath := exePath + 'XML_out\'; //correct directory

   wiadomosc := wiadomosc + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + 'FILES IN DIRECTORY:' + directoryPath; //will output correct directory
   //first method
   directoryEOFound:= False;
   if FindFirst(directoryPath, faAnyFile, directoryRes) = 0 then
      wiadomosc := wiadomosc + sLineBreak + 'DIRECTORY N)T FOUND' + sLineBreak //should save info about directory not found but return nothing
//     exit  //exit is killing app, like directory was not found.... but directory is there
   else
     while not directoryEOFound do begin
       wiadomosc := wiadomosc + sLineBreak + directoryRes.Name; //gives nothing
       directoryEOFound:= FindNext(directoryRes) <> 0;
     end;
   FindClose(directoryRes) ;


   //second method
  if FindFirst(directoryPath, faAnyFile, directoryRes) = 0 then try
    repeat
      if (directoryRes.Name = '.') or (directoryRes.Name = '..') then
        continue;

        wiadomosc := wiadomosc + sLineBreak + 'file: ' + directoryRes.Name;  //gives nothing, i dont think its initiated
    until FindNext(directoryRes) <> 0;
  finally
    SysUtils.FindClose(directoryRes);
  end;
```

Neither method works, so maybe its a OS matter? (windows 7 64 bit) No errors in compilation offcourse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a pattern to search for files. Replace

```
directoryPath := exePath + 'XML_out\';
```

with

```
directoryPath := exePath + 'XML_out\*';
```

---

The first block of code is odd. It appears to give up when `FindFirst` returns `0`. But the `0` return value indicates success. So that condition is wrong. The second block of code looks reasonable.